# Certain fractions being calculated in excel 2013

Tags: excel, format, fractions

I'm creating a simple spreadsheet to calculate some betting odds and keeping track of my wins/losses

when I put fractional odds in one column Excel converts some of them to whole numbers (i.e. the ones that are 1/1, 2/1, etc where it does not do it for odds like 4/11, 7/2, etc.

Is there a way of turning this off?

Please note that some of the top heave fractions (11/2, 11/10 etc) get put into whole numbers such as 5 1/2 etc! And I do not want this to occur either

I've tried the Custom formatting of the cells but all of the denominators will inevitably be different, so having something like ??/28 won't work for me

**EDIT:**

This was solved using the custom format `??/??` and simply removeing the `#` that was at the front of the custom cell format dialog box

Comment: It is not converting, it is using a different format. Try Clear/Formats, you will see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change the cell format; you want to use `???/???`. This will make *Excel* represent any decimal number to the closest fraction approximation it can find using the specified numerator and denominator significant digits (number of `?` in the format string)

If the cell input is directly a fraction, it will reduce it if possible but always keeping the fraction format.

Examples:

```
= .10  will be converted to 1/10
= 0.1231 will be converted to 81/658 (supossing ???/??? format is used).
= 10/100 will be converted to 1/10
= 11/12 will remain as 11/12 as no reduction is possible.
= 1/1 will remain as 1/1
etc.
```

The behavior you are describing is becuase you are using one of Excel's default fraction formats which are all similar to `# ???/???` (take note of the leading `#`). This format will reduce integral values to the non fractional part.

Comment: upon looking at the custom formats and removing the leading '#' this solved my problem so that I could enter fractions such as 21/10 etc without them being formed into 2 1/10 etc :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use text format for the cells with the odds, and then the `VALUE` function in any calculations you need to do with them